# An iPhone 7 charging case which plugs into Lightning cables

Tags: smartphones, power-bank

I used to have a Mophie Pack for my iPhone 5.  It was a charging case that plugged into Apple's Lightning cables.  But I just got an iPhone 7, and it seems that all the charging cases available for it, both by Mophie and by other companies, plug into micro-USB cables, i.e. the kind of cables used to charge Android devices.

So my question is, are there any iPhone 7 charging cases that plug into Lightning cables?  That would be much more convenient for me.

Comment: Is a case that plugs into a lightning cable your only requirement? Any budget, battery capacity preferences?

Comment: Yes, the lightning port is essentially my only requirement.  Budget isn't a consideration. Regarding battery capacity, I suppose the more, the better, but I don't have minimum capacity requirements or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [This Runsy iPhone 7 case](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LZVJ9SZ) It looks like it uses a lightning passthough, so you won't need to carry a pesky micro usb cable around. The only limitation is that it does not work with headphones with lightning connectors.

Overall, it has a 4 out of 5 star review. Let me know if this fits the bill.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.  And reading the reviews of that product, I found out that Apple itself makes a charging case, although it's $99 rather than $25: http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MN002LL/A/iphone-7-smart-battery-case-black

Comment: Well, that's the apply up-charge. I'm glad you found a couple viable options!